# Is there a single word for a group (teacher, student and parents) or a teacher communicating with a student?

Tags: translation, word-requests

I was wondering if there is a word that represents a teacher communicating with a student or a word that represents a group which consists of a teacher, student and parent, do any of these words exist?

Comment: What would examples of such words be in English?  This is pretty vague.  If you can give examples you know of in English, perhaps we can help you with Japanese.

Comment: I think wardship could refer to a teacher / parent of a student, I don't know of an example for the other, I guess there is no word for it, I was just wondering because some languages have words for situations

Comment: Hmm.  I would have no idea what *wardship* would mean.  I'm American. So maybe you're using a different register.  But *wardship* to me sounds like *guardianship* and not like anything related to teachers, students, or parents (except in the sense that a child is sometimes referred to as the *ward* of the parent).

Comment: I can think of words like classroom (教室) or school (学校) but I assume these are not the sorts of words you're looking for.  If you mean something like a PTSA association, then that's a different matter altogether.

Comment: There is a word for a meeting between a teacher, a student, and one of the student's parents, but I'm not sure if that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Although I doubt there are words you are looking for, it may be better to include information on the nature of the communication or what the group does or is intended for.

Comment: Could you tell me what this word is? @aguijonazo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am not sure if I am getting what you are asking, "[PTA](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/PTA)" is an acronym  for "Parent-Teacher Association", which sounds similar to "wardship" in your comment. Every student is more or less cognizant of PTA influencing their school indirectly.

An association for only teachers and students should be "[[生徒会]{せいとかい}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%94%9F%E5%BE%92%E4%BC%9A)". I think it is more of an autonomous group for students.

The literal translation of "wardship" should be [後援会]{こうえんかい}. Though it may differ between regions, it often applies to an athlete, an artist or a politician and so on and so forth.